# Prove of right regular pyramid that a perpendicular line in the middle of its height intersects its edge exactly in the middle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Prove of right regular pyramid that a perpendicular line in the middle of its height intersects its edge exactly in the middle.

It seems for me to be counter intuitive that this is the case. How sould I prove myself wrong?

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "a perpendicular line in the middle of its height"?

Comment: Please see the image. Excuse me my bad drawing skills.

Comment: have you tried a vector proof?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: draw just the triangle $\Delta TPA$ along with the perpendicular bisector of $TP$. You should be able to use similar triangles at that point

Comment: I proved it using Pythagorean theorem. It is the case because $\sqrt{(\frac{1}{2}TP)^2+(\frac{1}{2}AT)^2}=\frac{1}{2}AP$ and that should true because for when $\frac{1}{2}TP=\frac{1}{2}AT$ then using two additional triangles with that height and hypotenuse should produce a square for that to be possible those two triangles must be $\frac{1}{2}AP$ in length. And that's the case. Do you see any mistake here?

Comment: ... should produce a rectangle 3 by $\frac{1}{2}AP$.